# How to vertically align links and a button in a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Thanks for the wonderful opportunity.

I have a problem I facing hard time to solve right now due to my limited front end dev skills : I am trying to vertically align links with a button.

HTML here :

```
<nav>
    <div class="header_info">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Get Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</li></a>
            <li><a href="#">Suggestions</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="header-login">
        <div class="current header_user_info"><button><a href="#">test</a></button></div>
```

CSS here:

```
.header_info{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 10px;
    color: #7E7E7E;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    list-style:none;
    float: left;
}

.header_info ul{
     display: inline-block;
     list-style: none;
}


.header_info li{
    display: inline;
    margin-right:11px;
}

.header_info li :hover{
    color: #F98866;
}

.header_info a{
    color: #7E7E7E;
}
```

As you can see , the links and the buttons aren't on the same line and I would like to fix this so it can look neat and professional.

I would appreciate any help/enhancements of my code.

Thanks.

JSFIDDLE ==> https://jsfiddle.net/5nzvwwjx/5/

Comment: add margin https://jsfiddle.net/5nzvwwjx/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: flex; align-items: center;` on `nav`

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header_info {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: #7E7E7E;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

.header_info ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

.header_info li {
  margin-right: 11px;
  display: inline;
}

.header_info li:hover {
  color: #F98866;
}

.header_info a {
  color: #7E7E7E;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="header_info">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Get Help</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Suggestions</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="header-login">
    <div class="current header_user_info">
      <button><a href="#">test</a></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Or alternatively, you can make `.header_info` and `#header-login` `display: inline-block;` and that will center them currently, though if you add more content, using `vertical-align: middle;` will keep them aligned.

```css
.header_info {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: #7E7E7E;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.header_info ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

.header_info li {
  margin-right: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.header_info li:hover {
  color: #F98866;
}

.header_info a {
  color: #7E7E7E;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="header_info">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Get Help</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us<br>second line</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Suggestions</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="header-login">
    <div class="current header_user_info">
      <button><a href="#">test</a></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just move the button into the `ul` list like so:

```
<nav>
    <div class="header_info">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Get Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Suggestions</a></li>
            <li class="current header_user_info"><button><a href="#">test</a></button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I've also moved the classes onto the `li` if you still needed them for styling.

Answer (score 0):

I forked your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/yyb7p8o9/

I cleaned up the HTML, which had a few small issues.  Then, I added a 0px margin to style for "header_info ul" in the CSS:

```
.header_info ul{
     display: inline-block;
     list-style: none;
   margin: 0px
}
```